# How to view the Eclipse weblogic server startup script execution log?

Tags: windows, eclipse, logging, console, weblogic

I am trying to start the Weblogic server from the Eclipse. When i try to start the server, it gives an error saying "The syntax of the command is incorrect." in the console. I am not able to view what command it is trying to execute from the server startup script. Can anyone tell why this error is coming and also how to view the log for the startup being run in the eclipse console.(to know exactly on which windows command the above mentioned error is thrown). No other info is printed in the eclipse console window except the above mentioned error. 'startWebLogic.cmd' is set as the startup script that needs to be run on server startup from the domains folder.